# Connect USB keyboard to bluetooth

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I have an USB keyboard here, and I would like to connect it on bluetooth to other devices (mostly to android phones/phablets/tablets).

Yes, I know that buying a bluetooth keyboard would be more simple and cheap, but not this is what I want to do.

I know that using OTG to connect the USB device to the android directly could also work, and this is a feasible direction, but my this question focus to the other option:

*I am looking for a device, where I can plug my USB keyboard into, and my androids would see it as a bluetooth device from that point.*

Looking for that on the google/ebay/amazon, the search results are faded away by the reverse direction (connecting a bluetooth device over usb), or by for me irrelevant audio bluetooth transfer solutions. I simply can't find such a device there. (Possibly I did not use the correct search keywords.)

I think such an adapter would require also a battery or/and an external (probably USB) power source.

Price is not very important yet (currently I am only looking for the options), later I will likely buy the cheapest one on the ebay.

Comment: Any old phone, a USB-OTG cable and this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek ?

Comment: Or a Raspberry Pi: http://yetanotherpointlesstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/emulating-bluetooth-keyboard-with.html

Comment: @towe Thanks, it is a possible direction. But currently I am thinking on an OTG-less solution. Connecting the keyboard with OTG to another phone would not be OTG-less (but possible).

Comment: @towe Using a Raspberry pi for that would be like shooting flies by a cannon.

Comment: Maybe a Teensy on a custom PCB with an HC-05 bluetooth module. My suggestions seem to keep getting more and more DIY though.