# Wireless Mechanical Keyboard with L-shape ENTER key

Tags: keyboards

I prefer a "**backwards-L**" shaped ENTER key, **or at least** with an ENTER key that takes up two rows, as shown in the diagram.  Trying to find this feature in a **wireless, mechanical** keyboard. [image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious why the size of your enter key is so imperative to you that you would be willing to forgo almost all other keyboard factors besides being mechanical? I'd imagine that most wireless keyboards are designed for low weight and compact-ness, and therefore; they would be unlikely to provision space for a enter key that large.

Comment: @BennettYeo Nowadays the predominant layouts are [**ANSI and ISO**](https://deskthority.net/wiki/ANSI_vs_ISO).Over time I could get used to ANSI, but after coding many years with either ISO <Enter> or "Backwards-L" <Enter>, it's what I'm used to. I noticed for wired keyboards, both are easy to find, **but the vast majority of wireless appear to be ANSI layout, thus my request for a recommendation**.  Not sure why you think I am "willing to forgo almost all other keyboard factors."  I'm not.  Also, not all wireless are designed for compactness, especially gaming keyboards.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! Do you have a preference for size (full size, TKL, 70%, 60%)? What switches/switch type are you looking for? What's your budget? Any aesthetic considerations?

Comment: Where are you shopping? ANSI keyboards are US-style, all the keyboards in EU are ISO, so presumably if you broaden your search area to include the EU, you'll be tripping over ISO keyboards & ANSI get harder to find.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't wireless, but provides the *backwards-L* ENTER key you desire and is customizable: https://www.wasdkeyboards.com/wasd-v3-105-key-iso-custom-mechanical-keyboard.html

Comment: Partial answer or NAA. Possibly combining it with a possibly non-existing [usb-to-bluetooth adapter](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13755/24) might work.